# Calling a member function from a base class pointer with varying parameters depending on the derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm pretty experienced in C++, but I find myself struggling with this particular design problem.
I want to have a base class, that I can stuff in a std::map, with a virtual function that can be called generically by a method that is querying the map. But I want to be able to call that function from a base class pointer with different parameters, depending on what the derived type is. Something functionally similar to the following wildly illegal example:

```
class Base 
{
    virtual void doThing() = 0;
}

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    void doThing(int i, const std::string& s) {} // can't do that
}

class Derived2: public Base
{
    void doThing(double d, std::vector<int>& v) {} // can't do that either
}

enum class ID = {
    DERIVED1,
    DERIVED2
}

std::map<ID, std::unique_ptr<Base> thingmap = { ... }
std::unique_ptr<Base>& getThing(int) { return thingmap[i] };

int main(int I, const char* argv[]) {
    auto baseptr = getThing(DERIVED1); 
    baseptr->doThing(42, "hello world");
}
```

I don't want the caller to have to know what the derived type is, only that a Derived1 takes an int and a string. Downcasting isn't an option because the whole point of this is that I don't want the caller to have to specify the derived type explicitly. And C-style variable argument lists are yucky. :-)

Edited to clarify: I know exactly why the above can't possibly work, thank you. :-)  This is library code and I'm trying to conceal the internals of the library from the caller to the greatest extent possible. If there's a solution it probably involves a variadic template function.

Comment: So what should happen if `baseptr` points to `Derived2` and you call it with `42, "str"`?

Comment: you are trying to squeeze something into a polymorphic interface that isnt polymorphic. The caller must know what parameter to pass, so why do you want to given them only pointers to `Base` ?

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you focus too much on your attempt to solve something, but what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? How would a caller use `baseptr` if they don't know what derived it is? (when the caller does know what type it is then there are other ways than inheritance and using `Base` pointers)

Comment: for example would it be ok to have `SomeType x = getThing<SomeType>(); x.doThing(42,"hello world");` ?

Comment: The way to brute force it is to cast `baseptr` internally to the correct derived type. But then, this isn't really polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Your map is filled with `Base` instances, so the class **DO NOT** have the required prototypes implemented in `Derived1` or `Derived2`... And redefining overloaded methods do not implement the pure virtual method `doThing`, so `Derived1` and `Derived2` are still abstract classes and therefore cannot be instanciated.

Worst, your `getThing` function only deals with `Base`, so the compiler would **NEVER** allows you to use the overloaded signatures, since they don't exist **AT ALL** in `Base`. There is nothing to know the real class behind, since you don't use templates and implicit template argument deduction.

Your pattern cannot be done this way, period. Since you don't want to use neither downcasting nor explicitely specified child classes, you're stuck.
Even if you add all possible prototypes in `Base`, since it will be pure virtual methods, both derived classes will still be abstract classes. And if they aren't, then you'll never be able to know which one is a NOP and which one is implemented, since it will requires downcasting!

I think that you made a common mistake, even done by expert developers sometimes: you went into conception directly, BEFORE determining your real ROOT needs.

What you ask looks like the core system of a factory, and it's really not the good way to implement this design pattern and/or designing the specialized derived classes.

Comment: I know that. :-) I'm starting with what I want this API to look like and trying to figure out if it's possible to implement on the backend. I'm assuming any solution will look completely different from what I have above.

Comment: Yeah, I know, did the same mistake last year - and I eat C++ for the last 20 years... :) You must think the other way: what did you REALLY wanted to do, initially?